# How can I upgrade Cisco Nexus switch if not enough space for new image?

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus

I have Nexus 92348GC-X units with 9.3.7 image version and I need to upgrade them, BUT not enoght space on this devices for new image upload (nxos 9.3.9)
Moreover, I can't delete old image after I execute *allow delete boot-image* and try to delete due to some bug maybe. I can't delete it from bash too.

How can I upgrade switches in my case?

Comment: That's a "universal" image, so it should be compact'able, but Cisco's docs state that only works on 9300 series. (likely an oversight) They are, in theory, bootable by PXE.

Comment: @Ricky “In theory” being the important part. I would open a TAC case for Cisco to chime in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don’t say which model of Nexus switch you have (initially), but this is a common problem thanks to Cisco having little forethought with regard to storage space (among many other things).

One option is to use the Compact images rather than the “full” images.  See below for details and explanation.

> Early models of Cisco Nexus 3000, 3100, and 3500 Series switches with a model number that does not end in -XL have 1.4 to 1.6 gigabytes of storage space allocated to the bootflash. Over time, the file size of NX-OS software images has steadily increased to be over 1 gigabyte. As a result, it is difficult for Nexus 3000, 3100, and 3500 Series switches with a model number that does not end in -XL to simultaneously store more than one full NX-OS binary image at a time. Therefore, administrators cannot follow the standard NX-OS software upgrade procedure on Nexus 3000, 3100, and 3500 Series switches with a model number that does not end in -XL that is used for other Nexus platforms, such as Nexus 5000, 6000, 7000, and 9000 Series switches.
> Starting with NX-OS software release 7.0(3)I3(1), the file size of NX-OS software images can be reduced through the NX-OS Compact Image procedure. This is a non-disruptive procedure that does not affect the switch's control plane or ability to forward data plane traffic.

This is an excerpt from https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus3000/sw/upgrade/7_x/b_Cisco_Nexus_3000_Series_NX_OS_Software_Upgrade_and_Downgrade_Release_7_x/b_Cisco_Nexus_3000_Series_NX_OS_Software_Upgrade_and_Downgrade_Release_7_x_newGuide_chapter_01.html#id_61530

You could **possibly** use the compact image as a temporary solution in order to get rid of the “full” image from the device to free up space so that you can replace it with the “full” image you actually want to run (use the compact image as a placeholder).

Comment: I have   Nexus9000 C92348GC-X Chassis
And there is full version image as I see based on size of  image - 1959441408 bytes. 
I always thought that compact version is used for Nexus 3000 or other "small" models. As you say, I can use it for every nexus switch, right? Even for devices where full version was default installed? For instance, Nexus9000 C93180YC-FX

Comment: @VladimirFomin No. You didn’t list your model in your initial post.  And your understanding is correct, that the compact images are for smaller units. The compact images actually say compact as part of their file name, and there don’t seem to be any for your model.   That model is supposed to have 16GB of flash.  What do you have on there beside the image?

Comment: Right, this model [C93180YC-FX] supports 16GB, but model [C92348GC-X] supports only 4GB, 1.9 GB used by 9.3.7 image.
As you can see:
 2166505472 bytes used
 1926807552 bytes free
 4093313024 bytes total
1926807552 is not enough for 9.3.9 image

Comment: Do you know can I plug USB stick with 9.3.9 image and execute something like "boot nxos usbflash:/nxos.9.3.9.bin  Will it works? I mean, will switch loads from usb stick?

Comment: @VladimirFomin I think you need to open up a TAC case. C92348GC-X is supposed to have 8GB memory and a 16GB SSD according to Cisco’s datasheet. https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/nexus-9000-series-switches/datasheet-c78-735989.html